# Expand in series an equation of two variables

Tags: symbolic, series-expansion, expression-manipulation

I am sorry if this has been asked, I don't really know how to formulate  the search to find it.

We have some system of equations (that are equal to zero), for example (not sure how to enter expression with partial derivatives so it can be copy-pasted):

```
expr={4 (-1 + 3 x^2) (-1 + y) T[x, y]^2 - 
  x (-1 + x^2) (-2 + y) T[x, y] D[T[x, y], x] + 
  x (-1 + x^2) (-1 + y) y D[T[x, y], y] D[T[x, y], x], 
 x (-1 + x^2) T[x, y] D[S[x, y], x] + 
  S[x, y] ((2 - 6 x^2) T[x, y] + x (-1 + x^2) D[T[x, y], x])};
```

[image]

where `T[x,y]`, `S[x,y]` are some unknown funcitons. We want to solve the equations around `y=0` in a series expansion, so we define

```
T[x_, y_] = Sum[tx[jj, x]*y^jj, {jj, 0, 7}];
S[x_, y_] = Sum[sx[jj, x]*y^jj, {jj, 0, 7}];
```

and then to first order we have

```
Simplify[Series[expr, {y, 0, 0}]]
```

[image]

We see that we can solve the first equation with no problem

```
DSolve[
 SeriesCoefficient[Simplify[Series[expr, {y, 0, 0}]], 0][[1]] == 
  0, {tx[0, x]}, x]

{{tx[0, x] -> x^2 (1 - x^2)^2 C[1]}}
```

But then when we plug that solution back in, it doesn't quite work

```
Simplify[Series[
   expr, {y, 0, 0}] /. {tx -> Function[x, x^2 (1 - x^2)^2 C1]}]
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong? My question is basically how to enter in *Mathematica* objects like $a_n(x)$ (and also $a_n(x,y)$ or even $a_{n,m}(x,y)$) where $n$, ($m$) is a non-negative Integer (a dummy index) and $x$, ($y$) is a variable (Real/Complex depending on the problem), so that we can manipulate them like any other function.

Comment: You can simply write `DSolve[Normal@Series[expr, {y, 0, 0}] == {0, 0}, {tx[0, x], sx[0, x]},  x]` and get `{{sx[0, x] -> C[1], tx[0, x] -> x^2 (1 - x^2)^2 C[2]}}`.

Comment: @Alx I know that. This is just a simple example to indicate my question. My real problem includes 5 equations with 5 unknown variables which are very long and there this approach doesn't work.

Comment: Please, see my attempt to answer.

Comment: I don't fully understand your question but how about using `tx -> Function[{x,y}, x^2 (1 - x^2)^2 C1]` instead of `tx -> Function[x, x^2 (1 - x^2)^2 C1]`?

Comment: @HayashiYoshiaki I want to replace `tx[0, x]`, where the `0` is a dummy variable. At next order in the expansion it will be `tx[1, x]`. I don't see how making `tx` a function of `x` and `y` will help

Comment: @ThunderBiggi OK I got it. First you can try `Subscript` (Control key + _) to make `tx` and `ty` look more like a coefficient, then use `Subscript[tx,0] -> Function[{x,y},x^2 (1-x^2) C1]` . The reason of making the function of x and y even it is a function of only x is to convince Partial derivative function that its y derivative is 0. Another way to do similar thing is to use `SetAttributes` and `Constant`, but I don’t know whether it can make eg ‘a constant only respect to y’. Now I can’t use MA to test my suggestion. I hope you meet a good result.

Comment: @HayashiYoshiaki This works well for now - I have used it for a few problems. If you write it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can try `Subscript` (Control key + _) to make tx and ty look more like a coefficient, then use `Subscript[tx,0] -> Function[{x,y},x^2 (1-x^2) C1]`. The reason for making the function of x and y even when it is a function only of x is to convince the partial derivative function that its y derivative is 0. Another way to do similar things is to use `SetAttributes` and Constant, but I don’t know whether it can make eg ‘constant only respect to y’.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not complete answer, but some (clumsy) thoughts.

The idea is to introduce a dummy variable instead of `y` (`=0`) so that Mathematica can properly compute partial derivatives:

```
expr0 = Normal@
   Series[expr, {y, 0, 0}] /. {(t : (T | S))[x, 0] :> t[x, z], 
   Derivative[n_, m_][t : (T | S)][x, 0] -> Derivative[n, m][t][x, z]}
```

> `{-4*(-1 + 3*x^2)*T[x, z]^2 + 2*x*(-1 + x^2)*T[x, z]*Derivative[1, 0][T][x, z], 
>     x*(-1 + x^2)*T[x, z]*Derivative[1, 0][S][x, z] + 
>      S[x, z]*((2 - 6*x^2)*T[x, z] + x*(-1 + x^2)*Derivative[1, 0][T][x, z])}`

All the next is simple enough:

```
tsol = DSolve[expr0[[1]] == 0, T[x, z], x]
```

> `{{T[x, z] -> 0}, {T[x, z] -> x^2 (1 - x^2)^2 C[1]}}`

And for the second variable:

```
Block[{T}, T[x_, z_] = tsol[[2, 1, 2]]; 
 DSolve[expr0[[2]] == 0, S[x, z], x]]
```

> `{{S[x, z] -> C[2]}}`

Comment: This works for the zeroth order term, but if I want higher order terms I don't really see how to adapt it. I really want to obtain a solution to the equations for `T[x,y]` and `S[x,y]` as power series in `y`